# How to combine simple math with strings with php in MySQL query

Tags: php

I want to add a filter to my MySQL query based on users birthday.

Providing:

```
$cur_year = 2012
$cur_month = 07
$cur_day = 18
```

How do I do the difference `$cur_year - $minAge` and then display `-07-19` (month and day)

I'm trying this:

```
`Birthday` < $cur_year - $minAge'-$cur_month-$cur_day'
```

Comment: you ask about MySql but your code is PHP ?!

Comment: still not clear if you want to do it inside the query or using PHP code

Comment: Do you mean something like "Birthday: ".($cur_year - $minAge)."- $cur_month -$cur_day";?

Comment: Could you pleae add an example of the output you want given the example data you have? (Also add in what `$minAge` is so there is no miunderstanding?

Comment: The user inputs the age range $minAge = the minimum age, $maxAge the maximum age. The output should be the present date - min age. EG: if today is `2012-07-18` and min age = `20` it should return: `1992-07-18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *reasonably* certain you are trying to do something like this:

```
$minAge = 18;

$query = "
  SELECT
    `somecol`, `someothercol`,
    IF(DATE_ADD(`Birthday`, INTERVAL ".((int) $minAge)." YEAR) < NOW(), 1, 0) AS `isOldEnough`
  FROM `tablename`
  WHERE `somecol` = 'someval'
";
```

In each returned row, the `isOldEnough` key in the result will contain `1` if the user is 18 years old, or `0` if they aren't.

Comment: I ended up using: "`Birthday` < '".($cur_year-$minAge)."-$cur_month-$cur_day'" just noticed someone commented the idea. Anyway I'll accept this as it's the only answer and seems to work too.

Comment: @Liso22 This is definitely a better option than extracting the date strings from PHP, for one thing it only requires you to pass a single value, `$minAge` in the query. You should read up on the MySQL [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).